# Two staged training for different dependent graphs in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to perform two tasks (A and B) which have inputs `inp_A` and `inp_B` and corresponding outputs `out_A`, `out_B`.

Task A is to be first achieved by a Graph `g_A`. After Task A is finished, I wish to use the weights of `g_A` into a new graph `g_B` which is a bigger graph ( a superset of `g_A`).

I am unsure how to do this in tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this kind of split for training and validation purposes, where I create dedicated input and output pipelines but share the inception part of the graph, although I'm using the same *graph* (as of `tf.Graph()`), but different (unconnected) *subgraphs* within it.

Within one `tf.Graph()` the general concept is [variable sharing](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variable_scope/) which you can achieve by using `tf.variable_scope()` to group your variables by concept and them creating and refetching them by using `tf.get_variable()` (instead of using `tf.Variable()` directly). The first time it's called it will create the variables, the second time it will reuse them - provided the name of the variable stays the same.

However I found it much easier to use [`tf.make_template()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/sharing_variables#make_template) instead, which will wrap a function that creates a subgraph entirely and on every call creates a new instance of the graph while sharing all of its variables.
The documentation example for that is

```
def my_op(x, scalar_name):
  var1 = tf.get_variable(scalar_name,
                         shape=[],
                         initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1))
  return x * var1

create_instance = tf.make_template('scale_by_y', my_op, scalar_name='y')

z = create_instance(input1)
w = create_instance(input2)
```

Here, each call to `create_instance` will create a new node called `scale_by_y` in the graph that performs the operation defined by `my_op()` while sharing its internal variables. (In the example, the parameter `scalar_name` is statically bound to the value of `y`, resulting in variable `scale_by_y/y` to be created (and reused) in the graph. I find that to be more confusing than helpful.) 
It does not care about parent scopes, so

```
with tf.variable_scope('training'):
    z1 = create_instance(input1)

with tf.variable_scope('validation'):
    z2 = create_instance(input2)
```

works. It also might or might not work across different `tf.Graph()` instances, though I doubt it.